# Application of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (cosmological red-shift)

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics

1. The problem statement, all variables and given/known data

[image]

I am stuck on the section of my lecture notes attached, where it says that equation 4.20 follows from 4.18 via an application of the fundamental theorem of calculus

2. Relevant equations

FoC:

if $ f$ is cts on $[a,b]$ then the function :

$F(x)=\int\limits^{x}_{c} f(t) dt $

has a derivaitve at every point in $[a,b]$ and

$\frac{dF}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx} \int\limits^{x}_{a} f(t) dt=f(x) $

3. The attempt at a solution

I can't see the link since 4.18 says that:

Let me call $ \int dt \frac{1}{a(t)} = b(t) $, 4.18 says that $b(t_2)-b(t_1)=r_1 $ whilst 4.20 is looking at something completely different : $ b(t_2 + \Delta t_2)-b(t_1+\Delta t_1) $

(and so rather than an application of the FoC I thought it was expansion of $b(t)$ assuming $\Delta t_2 $ is small)

So it looks like we have used 4.18 s.t the RHS can be set to zero if there is some property from the FoC that allows to do some sort of split on the limits, a corollary following from the FoC or something that I'm not seeing?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that here $\Delta t_i$ is ''small'' . If so we can write:
$$
r=\int_{t_1+\Delta t_1}^{t_2+\Delta t_2}\frac{dt}{a(t)}=\int_{t_1+\Delta t_1}^{t_2}\frac{dt}{a(t)}+\int_{t_2}^{t_2+\Delta t_2}\frac{dt}{a(t)}=
$$
$$
\int_{t_2}^{t_2+\Delta t_2}\frac{dt}{a(t)}-\int_{t_1}^{t_1+\Delta t_1}\frac{dt}{a(t)}+\int_{t_1}^{t_2}\frac{dt}{a(t)}= \int_{t_2}^{t_2+\Delta t_2}\frac{dt}{a(t)}-\int_{t_1}^{t_1+\Delta t_1}\frac{dt}{a(t)}+r
$$

that, by fundamental theorem (using $\Delta t_i \to 0$ as usually does physicists), becomes

$$
0=\frac{\Delta t_2}{a(t_2)}-\frac{\Delta t_1}{a(t_1)}
$$

---

If $\frac{dF(x)}{dx}=f(x)$:
$$
\int_x^{x+\Delta x}f(t)dt=F(x+\Delta x)-F(x)= \Delta x F'(x)=\Delta x  \;f(x)
$$

(if $ \Delta x \to 0$)

Comment: many thanks for your reply. sorry could you please explain how the last step follows from the fundamental theorem of calculus, or, perhaps point to me the fundamental theorem of calculus written in a more suggestive form for this purpose? thanks

Comment: I added to my answer. I hope it's useful :)